# Can I give react query a timeout (seconds or milliseconds...) so after that amount of time it stops the network request?

Tags: reactjs, timeout, react-query

I want to use react-query and make a network request. I want to give my request a timeout so after that amount of time the network request is abandoned/timed out.

I've read through the useQuery docs and nothing listed seemed to fit this requirement.

Can I do this with react query? If not, what else would you suggest?
Thank you!

Comment: You can use [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) in the fetch function

Comment: is this with react-query still or not? @nullptr

Comment: with react query

Answer (score 6):

This is out of scope for react-query because react-query doesn't do any data fetching. It's an async state manager that is promise based, so you just return a resolved or rejected Promise and react-query will do the rest.

How you produce that promise is up to you. As others have said, if you use `axios` for data fetching, there are ways to attach a timeout to it. If you want to use `fetch`, I'd suggest using [ky](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky#timeout) as they also have support for timeouts.

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) to fetch the data, it has `timeout` option so you can specify this time limit after which axios will throw an error. Don't forget to disable react-query `retry` option if you only want to make request once:

```
  const { data } = useQuery(
    [key],
    // Use whatever timeout you need
    () => axios.get(url, { timeout: 5000 }),
  );
```

Comment: Ohhh, kind of didnt know i could use axios and react-query together...thank you!

Comment: @helen8297 mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your question, or make additional edits to the question if you still have unresolved issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `await-timeout` library.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-timeout
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/await-timeout

Your mutation hook will look something like this:

```
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';
import Timeout from 'await-timeout';

export const useSomeMutation = () => {
  return useMutation((props) => {
    const promise = doMutation(props);
    return Timeout.wrap(promise, 5000, 'Mutation timeout!'); // 5 seconds timeout
  }, {});
};
```

And your query hook will look something like this:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import Timeout from 'await-timeout';

export const useSomeQuery = () => {
  return useQuery(
    ['query','key'],
    async (props) => {
      const promise = getQuery(props);
      return Timeout.wrap(promise, 5000, 'Mutation timeout!'); // 5 seconds timeout
    };
  );
};
```